# Powershell remoting from domain controller to client

Tags: powershell, deployment, remote-access

So, i have a project where i want to learn how to deploy something like softwares to other computers on your client pc's on your domain network, like you do with group policies, but the longer and harder route (for me atleast).

I have enabled remoting, done the WinRM settings so that literally every pc in the world is trusted host (read it was a bad idea, but it is 2 newly installed machines with no connection to anything and it's just to get it to work), but i have some problems with a couple of stuff in this project.

First and foremost. I can easily remote connect to the 2 pc's, no problems there. The problem comes when i try to interact with a specific user on the pc. Like right now i have an Administrator and 2 client users, one called Lars Larsen and one called test.

When i try to get in remote connect to administrator or just the pc as a whole, no problem i get in, but when i try to get -credentials to the test user or Lars Larsen, then i get an error called:

> Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server 'my_pc' failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_remote_troubleshooting topic.
> At line:1 char:1
> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName *REDACTED* -Credential *REDACTED*
> Category Info: InvalidArgument: (pcname:string) [enter-pssession], PSRemotingTransportException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId: CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed

When i then try to just access the administrator user (which honestly just feels like it's the domain controllers own drive from the ADDC which has folders based on the domain the pc is on), and i try to navigate to the desktop, dump a text.txt to see if it works with this:

`New-Item c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.txt`

I get this error:

> Remote Host method get_windowSize is not implemented

And when i try to navigate to the test users desktop folder and create the txt file there, i get the error:

> New-Item : Access to the path 'c:\users\test\desktop' is denied

I am really stuck here, and i would love some help. Every guide i find about any of this has been of no help so far.

How do i "easiest" and simpliest get to deploy softwares to active directory users through powershell?

Comment: It's unclear whether the `Administrator` account you're using is the builtin Administrator of the domain or the local built Administrator account of the target system. Can you show us how you format the `-Credential` argument?

Comment: im pretty stupid when it comes to powershell as i am fairly new (or so i would say) so not sure what you want me to show you specifically, but to be honest, i am not even sure myself whether or not which "administrator" folder i get access too, but i think it is the Domain Controller Administrator account.

Comment: In the (redacted) error message you've posted, it shows that you're trying to remote using `Enter-PSSession`, and that you pass something to the `-Credential` parameter - what are you passing to it? `Administrator`? `Domain\Administrator`? `RemoteComputerName\Administrator`?

Comment: If the account you want to use is a _local account_ on the target machine, then you need to format the username as `RemoteComputerName\LarsLarsen`, but if the account you want to use is a _domain user_, then it needs to be `DomainName\LarsLarsen` - in either case, the account needs to be a member of the local `Administrators` group on the target machine

Comment: first of all, sorry for the delay in answer. just got back to work after a break.

Second of all, i will say, that the thing in the *Redacted* error message is just me hiding the actual name it is showing. right now i am trying to access a certain user instead of just getting access to the pc itself, since i want to deploy software to the users. For now i will try the ``DomainName\LarsLarsen`` as an example. 
Thanks for the assistance, will try out what you said and hope it will work.